# error while using groovy.sql Out parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, grails, groovy

I am trying to execute some stored procedures in groovy way.  I am able to do it quite easily by using straight JDBC but this does not seem in the spirit of Grails.

I am trying to call the stored procedure as:

```
sql.query( "{call web_GetCityStateByZip(?,?,?,?,?)}",[params.postalcode, 
sql.out(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR), sql.out(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR), 
sql.out(java.sql.Types.INTEGER), sql.out(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)]) { rs ->
   params.city = rs.getString(2)
   params.state = rs.getString(3)
}
```

I tried various ways like `sql.call`. I was trying to get output variable value after this.

Everytime error:

```
Message: Cannot register out parameter. 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot register out parameter. 
Class: SessionExpirationFilter
```

but this does not seem to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't have the rep to edit, but it would be nice if the code sample was formatted, and if there were some explanation of what the stored proc does.

Answer (score 1):

This is still unanswered, so I did a bit of digging although I don't fully understand the problem. The following turned up from the Groovy source, perhaps it's of some help:

This line seems to be the origin of the exception:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/xref/groovy/sql/Sql.html#1173

This would seem to indicate that you have a Statement object implementing PreparedStatement, when you need the subinterface CallableStatement, which has the registerOutParameter() method which should be ultimately invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Internet Friend,
If i write code like-

```
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
Connection conn
ResultSet rs
try {
        conn = sql.createConnection()
        CallableStatement callable = conn.prepareCall(
        "{call web_GetCityStateByZip(?,?,?,?,?)}")
         callable.setString("@p_Zip",params.postalcode)
         callable.registerOutParameter("@p_City",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
         callable.registerOutParameter("@p_State",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
         callable.registerOutParameter("@p_RetCode",java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
         callable.registerOutParameter("@p_Msg",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
         callable.execute()
        params.city = callable.getString(2)
        params.state = callable.getString(3)
    }
```

It working well in JDBC way. But i wanted to try it like the previous code using sql.query/sql.call.

Any comments??

Thanks
Sadhna

Answer (score 0):

groovy way could be this code:

```
def getHours(java.sql.Date date, User user) throws CallProceduresServiceException {

    log.info "Calling stored procedure for getting hours statistics."
    def procedure
    def hour
    try {
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource.url, user.username, user.password, dataSource.driverClassName)
        log.debug "Date(first param): '${date}'"

        procedure = "call ${dbPrefixName}.GK_WD_GET_SCHEDULED_TIME_SUM(?, ?, ?, ?)"
        log.debug "procedure: ${procedure}"

        sql.call("{${procedure}}", [date, Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.getType()), Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.getType()), Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.getType())]) {
            hourInDay, hourInWeek, hourInMonth -> 
            log.debug "Hours in day: '${hourInDay}'"
            log.debug "Hours in week: '${hourInWeek}'"
            log.debug "Hours in month: '${hourInMonth}'"
            hour = new Hour(hourInDay, hourInWeek, hourInMonth)
        }
        log.info "Procedure was executed."
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new CallProceduresServiceException("Executing sql procedure failed!"
                + "\nProcedure: ${procedure}", e)
    }       
    return hour 
}
```

In my app it works great.

Tomas Peterka